# MySQL error Fk: Foreign key references invalid table

Tags: mysql

This is error:

```
Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
Foreign key 'FK__Empresa__IdEmpre__164452B1' references invalid table 'Ciudad'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

This is the script:

```
CREATE TABLE Ciudad
(
    IdCiudad int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    Ciudad_Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Empresa
(
IdEmpresa INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
NIT_Empresa INT NOT NULL,
Nombre_Emp VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Dir_Emp VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Tel_Emp INT NOT NULL,
Email_Emp VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdEmpresa) REFERENCES Ciudad (IdCiudad),
FOREIGN KEY (IdEmpresa) REFERENCES Pais (IdPais),
)
```

Comment: did you check if ciudad was actually created? you have trailing commas on the final definition in each create query. and you cannot have a single FK pointing at two different tables/fields.

Comment: As far as i'm aware, you can't have an identity field be a FK to another identity field. The same with a PK, it can be a PK or an FK, not both

Comment: Your error says "See previous errors".   What are the previous errors?

Comment: I've just run this and it works fine for me (when i take out the FK to Pais as i don't have that table). I've formatted the errors so they make sense.

Comment: In fact, title says MySQL but it's tagged sql-server, which is it?

Comment: @RichBenner there is nothing that would prevent a column with the identity property from being used as a foreign key like this. It is however rather pointless and highly prone to being completely useless. You would only be able to have a 1:1 relationship and if the identities ever got out of synch you would be hosed. In short, the engine will allow it but it defies all logic.

Comment: @SeanLange you're absolutely right, it did work for me when I tested. I agree with you about this being a bad idea too.